# Generating random numbers with mt19937_64 for multithread monte carlo simulation

Tags: c++, multithreading, random, mersenne-twister

I am running a monte carlo simulation on multiple threads. I have a Draw class which handles random number generation. It uses mt19937-64 as the generator of  `std::uniform_real_distribution`.

```
template<typename T, typename R>
class Draw {
    T _dist;
    typedef decltype(_dist.min()) result_type;

    public:
    // Draw : T R -> Draw
    //! GIVEN
    //!   1. dist - A distribution.
    //!   2. gen - A random number generator.
    Draw(T dist, R gen) : _dist(dist), _gen(gen) {}

    virtual ~Draw() = default;

    // () : -> Value
    //! GIVEN
    //! RETURNS
    //! value drawn from the distribution, which can be any result type
    //!   supported by the distribution.
    result_type operator()() const { return _draw(); }

    // seed : NonNegInt -> Void
    //! GIVEN
    //!   1. seed - A random number generator (RNG) seed.
    //! EFFECT
    //!   Seeds the RNG with the given seed.
    void seed(unsigned long seed) { _gen.seed(seed);}

    private:
    R _gen;

    // draw : -> Value
    // GIVEN:
    // RETURNS: A value drawn from the distribution, which can be any result
    //          type supported by the distribution.
    std::function<result_type()> _draw = bind(_dist,_gen);
};

// standard uniform distribution ~ Unif(a=0, b=1)
class DrawUnif :
public Draw<std::uniform_real_distribution<double>,std::mt19937_64>
{
    typedef std::mt19937_64 genny;
    typedef std::chrono::system_clock clk;
    typedef std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist;

    public:
    DrawUnif() :
      Draw(dist{0,1}, genny(clk::now().time_since_epoch().count())) {}

    //! GIVEN
    //! -----
    //!   1. seed - A seed for the random number generator.
    DrawUnif(unsigned long seed) : Draw(dist{0,1}, genny(seed)) {}

     virtual ~DrawUnif() = default;
};
```

Each thread has access to the following shared pointer

```
  typedef std::shared_ptr<DrawUnif> DrawUnifShrPtr;
  DrawUnifShrPtr    _unif;
```

Which is initialized by

```
_unif(DrawUnifShrPtr(new DrawUnif { seed }));
```

Each thread has several functions which frequently call `draw(*_unif)` to generate a random number. The results seem correct but I am wondering if two threads call

```
draw(*_unif)
```

at the same time, what would happen?

Then I allocated a new shared_pointer with different seed to each cohort:

```
 _unif(std::make_shared<DrawUnif>(*c._unif));
 _unif->seed(a_new_seed);
```

Now the results look wiered! Each thread is getting exact same random!! numbers and provide exact same result. 
To summarize:

1- What would happen if multiple treads call the draw at the same time?

2- Why different seeds get exact same results.

Comment: I haven't had to deal with this before so I'm not 100% sure on this, but I thought that the STL random libraries were not thread safe in terms of being called at the same time. (You can use one generator/distribution in multiple threads as long as you take care of the synchronization I believe). Also, another issue with seeding random number generators in a multi-threaded environment is that if you seed based on time, a lot of the time functions have course resolution so multiple threads calling the same thing at about the same time are likely to get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

The random number support in the STL is not thread safe.  You could add that (at the expense of some run time performance), or go with separate random number generators for each thread.  Each thread's generator will need a distinct seed.  In its simplest form, this can be accomplished by incrementing the seed value for each new thread, but runs the risk of duplicate sequences if a new simulation is run too quickly.  You could also scale your existing seed value by an appropriate constant, then add the thread index to it.  Or you can look into `seed_sequence`s, and use the thread index or id as a secondary input into the sequence.

Comment: I am using seeds with increments of 1. Each thread is called almost immediately after the other one. If the seed is a user input and does not depend on time, why do yo say "runs the risk of duplicate sequences if a new simulation is run too quickly"?

Comment: @g1368 That refers to time based seeds.

Comment: @g1368 Each thread needs its own copy of `_unif` (and any other data that is written to during the simulation).

Comment: I understand that using seed_sequence might be a better approach. But do yo have any idea why I get exact same results with different seeds with increment of 1? I expected this to work fine!

Comment: Doesn't this mean separated copy of _unif for each thread?


     _unif(std::make_shared<DrawUnif>(*c._unif));

     _unif->seed(a_new_seed);

The outputs of each thread is written to a separate file.